# Is it possible to establish a direct serial communication between VST plugin in FL Studio and Arduino?

Tags: arduino, vst

My goal is to write a VST that generates 4 bytes of data based on 3 parameters. So i've made an algorithm that basically turns music into color with ZGameEditorVisualizer VST and 3 parameters (low,mid,high control the hue, lightness and saturation). My problem is that this can only make video (that's what the VST is intended for. However i want to use live, these colors should be projected on my RGB led strip, which will be connected to the arduino. For that i will need to write a VST that can generate RGB data from Hue, Saturation and Lightness. So it generates 4 bytes, (Red,Green,Blue,Alpha) and needs to send it over to the Arduino. Arduino then makes them shine beautifully. What i need help with, is where do i get started? Is it possible to connect a VST to Serial Communication? How can i use these 3 parameters to make RGB? Is there a library for that for C++? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure. Any program on a PC can use serial. But how are you going to get your hue data? Compared to writing a VST and the algorithm to produce these RGB values, accessing serial is a walk in the park. Are you sure you up for this?